# Sabre Searching PNR

Tags: c#, web-services, soapui, sabre

I've done some tests using the SoapUI Project on development but when I'm trying to execute the Trip_Search API, I'm only be able to get the PNR numbers through Name Criteria and the View TripSearchTN, if I use other criteria or View, It doesn't work.

Also, the response is only the PNR number, I'm not getting the itinerary info,

Can you help me to figure out what Am I doing wrong please?

Thanks

Request:

```
<Trip_SearchRQ Version="4.2.0" EchoToken="ECHO" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/triprecord">
  <ReadRequests>
    <ReservationReadRequest>
        <NameCriteria>
        <Name>
          <FirstName MatchMode="EXACT">DLC</FirstName>
          <LastName MatchMode="SIMILAR">TEST</LastName>
        </Name>
      </NameCriteria>
      <PosCriteria AirlineCode="AA">
        <Pcc>ipcc</Pcc>
      </PosCriteria>
      <ReturnOptions MaxItemsReturned="200" ResponseFormat="STL" ViewName="TripSearchTN"/>
    </ReservationReadRequest>
  </ReadRequests>
</Trip_SearchRQ>
```

Response:

```
<Trip_SearchRS EchoToken="ECHO" TimeStamp="2016-01-29T17:50:48" Target="Test" Version="4.2.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/triprecord" xmlns:ns9="http://www.sabre.com/ssg/des/v1" xmlns:ns5="http://tds.sabre.com/rules" xmlns:ns12="http://www.sabre.com/eps/schemas" xmlns:ns13="http://tds.sabre.com/distribution" xmlns:ns6="http://tds.sabre.com/itinerary" xmlns:ns7="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Header/v02_00" xmlns:ns10="http://www.OpenTravel.org/ns/OTA2/AppInfo_v01_00" xmlns:ns8="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v02" xmlns:ns11="http://opentravel.org/common/v02" xmlns:ns2="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" xmlns:ns4="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07" xmlns:ns3="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder">
         <Success>Success</Success>
         <ReservationsList NumberResults="3" NumberPages="1" TotalResults="3">
            <Reservations>
               <Reservation Locator="OQGCOA">
                  <ns3:GetReservationRS>
                     <ns3:Reservation>
                        <ns3:BookingDetails>
                           <ns3:RecordLocator>OQGCOA</ns3:RecordLocator>
                           <ns3:CreationTimestamp>2016-01-29T09:40:00</ns3:CreationTimestamp>
                        </ns3:BookingDetails>
                        <ns3:POS>
                           <ns3:Source PseudoCityCode="ipcc" AirlineVendorID="AA"/>
                        </ns3:POS>
                        <ns3:PassengerReservation/>
                     </ns3:Reservation>
                  </ns3:GetReservationRS>
               </Reservation>
               <Reservation Locator="VVFMOE">
                  <ns3:GetReservationRS>
                     <ns3:Reservation>
                        <ns3:BookingDetails>
                           <ns3:RecordLocator>VVFMOE</ns3:RecordLocator>
                           <ns3:CreationTimestamp>2016-01-28T09:05:00</ns3:CreationTimestamp>
                        </ns3:BookingDetails>
                        <ns3:POS>
                           <ns3:Source PseudoCityCode="ipcc" AirlineVendorID="AA"/>
                        </ns3:POS>
                        <ns3:PassengerReservation/>
                     </ns3:Reservation>
                  </ns3:GetReservationRS>
               </Reservation>
               <Reservation Locator="VVGNID">
                  <ns3:GetReservationRS>
                     <ns3:Reservation>
                        <ns3:BookingDetails>
                           <ns3:RecordLocator>VVGNID</ns3:RecordLocator>
                           <ns3:CreationTimestamp>2016-01-28T09:07:00</ns3:CreationTimestamp>
                        </ns3:BookingDetails>
                        <ns3:POS>
                           <ns3:Source PseudoCityCode="ipcc" AirlineVendorID="AA"/>
                        </ns3:POS>
                        <ns3:PassengerReservation/>
                     </ns3:Reservation>
                  </ns3:GetReservationRS>
               </Reservation>
            </Reservations>
         </ReservationsList>
      </Trip_SearchRS>
```

Comment: I believe that you need to check the service provider or concerned developer if it is internal to you, appears that it could be an issue in the application if it is not working as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `ReturnOptions's` `ViewName` property to FULL

`<ReturnOptions ViewName="FULL" ...`

Comment: Thanks for your response

Actually I've already done it but I'm not getting any results, Also I have tried with different search criteria and only works with Name Criteria.

You have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know... You may try adding SubjectAreas node within ReturnOptions

`<ReturnOptions ...>
  <SubjectAreas>
    <SubjectArea>HEADER</SubjectArea>
    <SubjectArea>NAME</SubjectArea>
    <SubjectArea>PASSENGERDETAILS</SubjectArea>
   </SubjectAreas>
</ReturnOptions>`

if that does not work - contact with their support.